# How to restrict user input to hexadecimal value in React?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs, html-input

This is my input:
[image]

This is its definition:

```html
<Input
  // type="number"
  id="numeroSerie"
  name="num_serie"
  defaultValue={this.state.num_serie}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  required
  pattern="[a-fA-F0-9]+"
  maxlength="1"
/>;
```

Using `pattern="[a-fA-F0-9]+"` means that the user can enter whatever he wants and then the validation will be performed when he clicks on the form submit button.
What I would like is:

**When the user clicks on any letter or a number that isn't hexadecimal, the input value would not change.** Just like when the input type is number, and the user tries to enter a text.

Is this possible to implement?

Comment: type="text" works

Comment: Could you create an online fiddle showing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid illegal input (`the input value would not change`):

Add a regex condition inside the handler function would be fine.

```
/^[0-9a-f]+$/.test(yourValue) // hexadecimal
```

- Test case: hexadecimal: https://www.regextester.com/93640

```js
const {useState} = React;

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const onChange = e => {
    const input = e.currentTarget.value;
    if (/^[0-9a-f]+$/.test(input) || input === "") {
      setValue(input);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="numeroSerie"
        name="num_serie"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works, but it still presents a problem, when the user enters an illegal character, it still gets displayed on the input field whereas it shouldn't.

Comment: my bad, man. I was using defaultValue instead of value in the input. Thank you so much it works perfectly

Comment: @AhmedGhrib Yeah, since you have fully controlled the component, you don't need `defaultValue` any more

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses the `onkeyup` event of the input element to test the content against an arbitrary regular expression. That means that the input element might momentarily display an illegal character but after the regex test reveals the content to be illegal, the prior contents will be restored. Using the `onkeyup` event greatly simplifies processing.

```js
function setupField(field, re)
{
    field.autocomplete = "off";
    field.saveValue = field.value;
    field.onkeyup = function() {
        var v = field.value;
        if (v === '' || re.test(v)) {
            field.saveValue = v;
        }
        else {
            field.value = field.saveValue;
        }
    };
}

setupField(document.getElementById('hex'), /^[A-Fa-f0-9]+$/);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="hex" size="8">
```

Comment: This is also works. But, the React solution, mentioned above is more comprehensive and effective.